# TFS 2015 - Team Project won't delete, stays as Queued in status

Tags: tfs-2015

Trying to delete projects from the Admin console in TFS 2015.  State changes to "deleting", listed as "Queued" in the Status tab, never completes.

There's currently several jobs listed as "queued" in the Status tab, some from many months back. Trying to select View Log, never gets past "Waiting for the job to start", which makes sense cause it's queued.

Not sure if/why one of the older jobs are stuck or otherwise blocking up the later ones.  Can delete requests be cancelled to see if the later ones will run properly?

Comment: Have your issue been solved? Give a try through command line which may do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

TFS uses SQL jobs to do all kinds of maintenance. Can you check if they are running as scheduled?

Looking further, it seems to be a Windows service:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/architecture/background-job-agent

Comment: I can certainly check - got a source with details so I know what to ask for/about?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try with [deleting a team project with *TFSDeleteProject* command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/command-line/tfsdeleteproject-cmd)

```
TFSDeleteproject [/q] [/force] [/excludewss] /collection:URL TeamProjectName
```

Also increase the Time-Out Period.

> By default, each Web service call that the TFSDeleteProject command
>   issues to delete a component must complete within 10 minutes.

Another thing is restarting the [Team Foundation Background Job Agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/architecture/background-job-agent) service in your TFS server.